# Unity Prefab The name `mainCamera' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting the error The name `mainCamera' does not exist in the current context for the line`targetPos = (Vector2)mainCamera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);`. I have search for an answer but cannot find a way to stop this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    float speed = 2f;
    Vector2 targetPos;

    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    private Animator myAnim;

    private static bool playerExists;
    public GameObject cameraPrefab;

    private void Start()
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        if(!playerExists){
            playerExists = true;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
        } else {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        targetPos = transform.position;

        GameObject mainCamera = (GameObject)Instantiate(cameraPrefab);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            targetPos = (Vector2)mainCamera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }
        if ((Vector2)transform.position != targetPos)
        {
            Move();
        } else {
            myAnim.SetBool("PlayerMoving", false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is in your `CameraPrefab`? Is there an enabled camera in there?  From the feedback on my answer it seems like you don't have a camera in the scene at all.

Comment: I have located the problem after you highlight that it has to be an issue with no active camera in the scene. I still cant find why I either get two cameras without the check or none with it.

Comment: `Update` gets called every frame, so on the 2nd frame, no matter how many cameras you actually have at the game start, on the second frame you'll have one camera that gets that update gets called, `cameraExists` is true, and then that camera gets destroyed.  Does `cameraPrefab` exist in the scene at game start? If so, you don't need to `Instantiate` it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that particular error because `mainCamera` is a local variable defined in `Start`. It is out of scope where you try to reference it in `Update`. You probably meant to define it as a field in your class, so you could reference it with `mainCamera` anywhere in your class. To do that you should do this instead:

```
// ...

private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
private Animator myAnim;

private static bool playerExists;
public GameObject cameraPrefab; 
public GameObject mainCamera; // add this line

private void Start()
{
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    if(!playerExists){
        playerExists = true;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    } else {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    targetPos = transform.position;

    mainCamera = (GameObject)Instantiate(cameraPrefab); // use mainCamera field
    mainCamera.tag = "MainCamera"; // tell Unity that it is your main camera.
}

// ...
```

But anyway, `Camera.main` is a static property of the `Camera` class, so you should access it through the `Camera` class anyway.

You should use this in `Update` instead:

```
targetPos = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```

Comment: I was using `targetPos = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);` until I made the camera a prefab. Then I was getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Unfortunatly I now get the error Type `UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'main' and no extension method 'main' of type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?` when I use `targetPos = (Vector2)mainCamera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);`

Comment: That means you don't have a main camera. If `mainCamera` is actually supposed to be the main camera, and the prefab isn't already set to have `"MainCamera"` as its tag, then you need to do that in script. I edited my answer to include that in the first code block.

Comment: I have update the code but when I run the game I get the message on screen saying No Cameras Rendering using `targetPos = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);` No errors in the code showing